# Working PyChef build for python 3.5.x

Tags: python, setup.py, pychef

I am attempting to run the setup for the https://github.com/coderanger/pychef/commits/master Master branch.  When I run the following command I am getting the resulting error and no installation:

## repo root directory contains

```
python setup.py
```

## resulting error:

```
> C:\...\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\setuptools-19.2-py3.5.egg\setuptools\dist.py:284:
> UserWarning: Normalizing '0.2.4-dev' to '0.2.4.dev0' usage: setup.py
> [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]    or: setup.py
> --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]    or: setup.py --help-commands    or: setup.py cmd --help
> 
> error: no commands supplied
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a command to `setup.py`:

```
$ python setup.py build
$ sudo python setup.py install
```

You may run `python setup.py --help-commands` to get the list of all possible commands:

```
Standard commands:
  build             build everything needed to install
  build_py          "build" pure Python modules (copy to build directory)
  build_ext         build C/C++ and Cython extensions (compile/link to build directory)
  build_clib        build C/C++ libraries used by Python extensions
  build_scripts     "build" scripts (copy and fixup #! line)
  clean             clean up temporary files from 'build' command
  install           install everything from build directory
  install_lib       install all Python modules (extensions and pure Python)
  install_headers   install C/C++ header files
  install_scripts   install scripts (Python or otherwise)
  install_data      install data files
  sdist             create a source distribution (tarball, zip file, etc.)
  register          register the distribution with the Python package index
  bdist             create a built (binary) distribution
  bdist_dumb        create a "dumb" built distribution
  bdist_rpm         create an RPM distribution
  bdist_wininst     create an executable installer for MS Windows
  upload            upload binary package to PyPI
  check             perform some checks on the package
```